# Is the Game Boy Advance slot on the DS region-locked?

Tags: region-lock, nintendo-ds, game-boy-advance

Would I be able to play an American Game Boy Advance game on my European DS via the GBA slot at the bottom of the device?

I know the on the whole Nintendo don't region-lock their portables (at least before the 3DS came out) but I just want to be 100% sure.

Comment: FWIW, the 3DS is region-locked.

Comment: @KatieK seriously?! Stupid Nintendo...

Comment: More specifically, 3DS/DSi/DSiWare games are region-locked. DS games from any region still work with DSis and 3DSs from any region.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not region-locked. I've played European, North American, and Japanese games on European and North American DS / DS Lites.

GBA-esque DS addons like the Daigasso expansion pack, paddle controller, and rumble pack are also not region-locked.